# Powershell start IE in private and log in to page

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate a process of activating accounts by logging in to email, I have it working when I am not on the business network with the following code.

```
$username = "user" 
$password = "pass" 
$url = "url"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate($url) 

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}   

$usernamefield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('UsernameTextBox')
$usernamefield.value = $username

$passwordfield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('PasswordTextBox')
$passwordfield.value = $password

$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SubmitButton").click()`
```

My issue is that once connected to the business network it then uses SSO to log in so I do not get the option to put in a username and password. To be able to put in a username and password I need to start IE in private mode. I have been able to start IE in private with the start-process command but I cannot find a way to select the window to type in the username and password.

Is there a way I can use powershell to log in to the website in a private browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a handle to the private IE by starting it with start-process, as you referred to.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList ' -private http://bogus.bogus'
```

Then you can connect to it by finding it -

```
$Shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$apps = $shell.windows()
$ie = $apps | where { $_.locationname -eq 'http://bogus.bogus/' }
```

Happy scripting.  :)

Comment: How to login using credentials ?